# MySQL and PHP table not printing right

Tags: php, mysql, database, html-table, view

This is for a class project in my databases class. I am making an event database and on the index page I want to make a table that joins the 3 tables in my db. right now all the data is on one table but I want to join all the tables. tables(Sports, Concert, and Restaurant)

```
<?php
include 'database_connector.php';

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$result=mysqli_query($con, "select *from Sports LIMIT 0, 30");
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>
  <th>Event Type</th>
  <th>Team 1</th>
  <th>Team 2</th>
  <th>Place</th>
  <th>Price</th></tr>"; 
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
 $event    = $row['event'];
 $team1    = $row['Team 1'];
 $team2    = $row['Team 2'];
 $place    = $row['Place'];
 $price    = $row['Price'];
 echo "<tr><td>".$event."</td>
    <td>".$team1."</td>
    <td>".$team2."</td>
    <td>".$place."</td>
    <td>" '$'.$price."</td></tr>"; 
} 
echo "</table>"
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to put a dollar sign in the last column to tell the people viewing the website that is what it costs

Comment: Sidenote: What's with the `?>` at the top of your code? Delete it. Plus, space this out `select *from` to `select * from`

Comment: Also, you have spaces in `['Team 1']` and `['Team 2']` which could be a factor. You will also want to put a semi-colon at the end of `echo "</table>"`

Comment: For the dollar sign, use `<td>" . "$" .$price."</td></tr>";`

Comment: the ?> is my mysqli connect statement dont want everyone know how to connect to it

Comment: You've been given examples, now it's up to "you" to make it work. @swimmerbhs

Comment: I got it to work the way I need it to. now just designing the website around it Thank You guys